# Finding Longest orf from 6 reading frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, biopython

I am trying the following code to fine the longest ORF from DNA sequence

```
from Bio import Seq
import regex as re
startP = re.compile('ATG')
nuc = input_seq.replace('\n','')
longest = (0,)
for m in startP.finditer(nuc, overlapped=True):
    if len(Seq.Seq(nuc)[m.start():].translate(to_stop=True)) > longest[0]:
        pro = Seq.Seq(nuc)[m.start():].translate(to_stop=True)
        longest = (len(pro), 
                   m.start(), 
                   str(pro),
                   nuc[m.start():m.start()+len(pro)*3+3])
```

But the problem is it only finds ORF in the 3 forward strands and doesn't cater to the reverse DNA strand.
TO take the reverse complement of the given sequence I have this script

```
# Swap characters
ReverseCompDNA = {'A': 'T', 'T': 'A', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C'}
def reverse_complement(seq):
    """
    reverse_complement function takes the single argument as sequence
    return the reverse+complement ordered. 
    """
    # Swapping A with T and G with C vice versa. Reversing newly generated string
    # https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-docstrings/
    
    return ''.join([ReverseCompDNA[nuc] for nuc in seq])[::-1]
```

I want my code to take both forward "Usual input and reverse after filtering the functional and give me the exact output after comparing all the ORFs from the DNA sequence of 6 ORFs.

Answer (score 1):

You are using BioPython so no need to implement your own `reverse_complement` function, use [the method from the `Seq` module](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.Seq.html#Bio.Seq.Seq.reverse_complement).

There is a sample in the BioPython cookbook about [identifying open reading frames](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec384), we can adapt that to find the longest ORF:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
record = SeqIO.read("NC_005816.fna", "fasta")
table = 11 #  This is a bacterial sequence, so using NCBI codon table 11. Adapt to your own needs

longest = 0
orf = None
strand = None
frame = None

for strand, nuc in [(+1, record.seq), (-1, record.seq.reverse_complement())]:
  for frame in range(3):
    length = 3 * ((len(record)-frame) // 3) #Multiple of three
    for pro in nuc[frame:frame+length].translate(table).split("*"):
      if len(pro) > longest:
        longest = len(pro)
        orf = pro
        strand = strand
        frame = frame

print(f"Longest ORF is {orf[:30]}...{orf[-3:]} with length {longest} at strand {strand}, frame {frame}.")
```

In the case of [NC_005816.fna](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/biopython/biopython/master/Tests/GenBank/NC_005816.fna) this prints:

```
Longest ORF is RGIFMSDTMVVNGSGGVPAFLFSGSTLSSY...LLK with length 361 at strand -1, frame 2.
```

Comment: Sir @BioGeek I want to take input from the user and the above codes gives an error on that AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seq'

Comment: Thank @bioGeek for the help. I resolved the issue with your kind comment.  I converted the string in Seq object. How to find the starting and ending index of our ORF ?